# Google maps API get multiple places from API call

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to call the Google maps API and have it return me a map that has the following.

1. Centered on the adress I'm giving the API call.
2. Icons for all nearby supermarkets, schools, fitness and train stations.

I know you can get all supermarkets by typing in "Supermarket" on google maps, but I need to get the supermarkets and more through the API, while being centered on the adress that I'm sending.

I expect the call to look something like this: 
http://maps.google.com/?q=teststreet&supermarket&fitness&school&train

Edit: 
I've found you can actually do what I wanted here: 
https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features

The only problem is that the URL is returning me a 404, so I'm probably not building it properly.
Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&types=supermarkt|trein|school|fitness"></script>

    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = { zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644) };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places Not sure what your question has to do with the title though...

Comment: @geocodezip My bad, it still had the title from a previous question that I never asked. It's properly changed now.

Comment: To do multiple searches with the places API, you need to call it multiple times (being aware of and handling the query limit appropriately).

Comment: But will it put the results into the same map? I don't want to end up with 5 maps on 1 page.

Comment: Are you asking if _your_ code will put the locations on the same map? We can't tell, you haven't provided any code that shows how you are planning on using the data.  You can certainly write the code either way.

Comment: @geocodezip I didn't have a proper example but I have one now, and added it to the question.